# Is it safe for a CFL bulb in a ceiling fixture to touch the glass of the fixture itself?

Tags: light-fixture

My fixture is an old style one with a 2 1/2" clearance from the top edge of the fixture to the ceiling.

Any advice?

Concerned homeowner 47

Comment: CFLs cause headaches.  My advice is to replace your light bulb with one that does not cause headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe. The CFL touching the glass probably heats it less than the incandescent did an inch or two away.